# Setting up a schedule task

Tags: force.com, scheduled-apex

I have set up a schedule task as per instructions [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm):
To turn the scheduling on, I open a dev console and do:

```
MY_NS.MyScheduleTask = new MY_NS.MyScheduleTask ();
String sch = '35 27 15 1 3 ?';
System.Schedule('MyScheduleTask', sch, p);
```

However, if I packing my code I don't want users to have to run this code from the dev console. Instead, I like a system administrator to just turn it on.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is apex scheduling you want to do without doing it from code, you'll have to go to:

1. Your Name -> Setup
2. App Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes
3. Schedule Apex button at the top
4. Here you can manually schedule an apex class which implemented the `Schedulable` interface

[image]
[image]

Comment: can't see this. What privileges do I need?

Comment: I can't seem to find any specific permissions, so i'd guess you just need the permission to create apex. I checked in over 10 orgs, ranging from developer, to partner developer, enterprise, force.com, ... and everywhere I seem to have access to the button

Comment: by the way: perhaps you looked next to it, the button is in the same row as "Run All Tests", I have added a screenshot to my answer, please check it out

Answer (score 4):

It is just Apex code. I don't see why you couldn't make it part of a controller action somewhere that functions off of a button click. That should work fine.

Comment: Agreed, you could create a quick VF UI to wrap around the Apex logic and then buttons to enable it, or even to delete it.